# Onchange Ajax method to load values from database work correct but how to change textarea value multiply with another textbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'am using Ajax call to load on-change value from database into text-area with all values and their quantity in one text-area. Now I want to change this text-area value to change when I entered a value in another text-box and multiply with all quantity value of text-area.
I am new to JavaScript and ajax so help me guys. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#location').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'location.php?location=' + $(this).val(),
            type: "get",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var material_name = data.material_name;
                var material_quantity = data.product_quantity;
                var data_material = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < material_name.length; i++) {
                    data_material += material_name[i] + "   : " + material_quantity[i] + " ";
                }
                document.getElementById("material_name").value = data_material;
                document.getElementById("material_quantity1").value = data.product_quantity;
            },
            error: function () {}
        });
        $('#quantity').keyup(function () {
            var price = document.getElementById('material_quantity').value;
            //document.getElementById("price_hidden").value=price;
            var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var total = quantity * price;
            document.getElementById("total").value = total;
            document.getElementById("total_hidden").value = document.getElementById("total").value;
        });
    });
});
```

I want to change all values of text-box with ID #material_quantity1  value when I entered any quantity in other text-box. 
Like in my textbox I have 15,20,25 now if I entered 5 then it will show 75,100,125.

Comment: Why are you binding an event in another event handler? `I want to change all values of text-box with ID #material_quantity1 value when I entered any quantity in other text-box.` Which textbox exactly?

Comment: "all values of text-box with ID #material_quantity1 value" You shouldn't have elements with the same ID. Use 'class' instead.

Comment: text-box with ID #material_quantity1.. in this text-box I have three values from my database like 10.15,20.. Now in other text-box ID #quantity if i entered 2 then it will show me like this 20,30,40.

Comment: try this Simply use `$('#quantity').trigger('keyup')` after line `document.getElementById("material_quantity1").value = data.product_quantity;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textarea1').live('blur',function(){ // Textarea in which you will enter the value..
   var textarea1 = $('#textarea').val(); // Textarea which will contain 152025..
   // if your value containts commas then you can use $('#textarea').val().replace(/,/g , ""); instead of $('#textarea').val();

   var final_value = $(this).val()*textarea1; // Put this value in the textarea you want...

});

//Add the below function this will replace your numbers with commas

function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(param1) {
        var x=param1.toString();
        var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
        var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
        if(otherNumbers != '')
            lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
        var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Yes It will contain comma but now if I 'm using this .replace() it will show total value not exactly that i want like 1,5,3 multiply 2 it will show me 306 not 2,10,6.

Comment: add ReplaceNumberWithCommas() function (I have added this function in my answer above) it will change the number 1000 to 1,000 and so on

Comment: Hi Sanket you don't understand my problem i don't want comma here I want exact solution. Replacing with comma (1,5,3 *2 )just give me 3,0,6 but i want 2,10,6.

Comment: you can split the string by .split(","); and then using for you can multiply the numbers for e.g. var abc = '1,5,3'; after split you will have an var array  = new Array('1','5','3'); then use for and multiple  numbers i.e. 1*2 = 2; 5*2 = 10; 3*2 = 6; and then use .toString(); this function converts array to string... I hope this is what you want.

Comment: @Ash Your welcome.. Can you please mark my comment as useful.